# How to wrap all home content of the MaterialApp with another Widget (listening to network connectivity always)?

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter 3.16.5 and do have one architecture question.

**My Goals**:

1. Listen to internet connectivity the entire time and show a flashbar if there is no internet.
2. Redirect (open) no internet page only if there is no internet right after opening the app (first state unknown, second one no_internet).
3. Do this in such a way that I can still access localizations and the navigator

**I tried**

**1. Wrapping `home` of `MaterialApp` with my widget that listens to network status `ConnectivityStatusListener`**

```
MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: supportedLocales,
          locale: state.locale,
          onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => S.of(context).title,
          home: ConnectivityStatusListener(child: const SplashScreen(),),
        )
```

`ConnectivityStatusListener`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class ConnectivityStatusListener extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConnectivityStatusListener({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<ConnectivityCubit, ConnectivityStatus>(
      listenWhen: (oldState, newState) =>
      oldState == ConnectivityStatus.unknown &&
          newState == ConnectivityStatus.none,
      listener: (context, state) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          NoConnectionScreen.route(),
        );
      },
      child: BlocListener<ConnectivityCubit, ConnectivityStatus>(
        listenWhen: (oldState, newState) =>
        oldState != ConnectivityStatus.unknown &&
            newState == ConnectivityStatus.none,
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO show flashbar
        },
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This approach failed because once another bloc of mine `UserBloc` returns the status of the user (authorized or guest) I do `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(` in the HomeScreen or LoginScreen.
(code for that is not here, but a navigation like that happens).
I do pushAndRemoveUntil because don't want to keep the SplashScreen in the stack as it is useless. The users might go there by mistake and get stuck.

I do notice that this makes `ConnectivityStatusListener` go out of the scope (probably popeed...) and the BlocListener there doesn't work anymore

**2. Adding state mixing on the `App`**

Some minor pseudocode that I tried:

```
class AppState with ConnectivityStatusListenerMixin {
// build and return app as above
}
```

example content of `ConnectivityStatusListenerMixin`

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:my_app/src/l10n/l10n.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

mixin ConnectivityStatusListenerMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  late StreamSubscription _connectivityStatusStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final navigationBloc = BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context);


    // Needs to be done after render so that the navigatorKey is already assigned
    // We can't navigate through MaterialAppContext directly
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final connectivityCubit = BlocProvider.of<ConnectivityCubit>(context);
      _connectivityStatusStream = connectivityCubit.stream.listen((event) async {
        // When first emitted status is 'no connectivity'.
        if (connectivityCubit.lastState == ConnectivityStatus.unknown &&
            event == ConnectivityStatus.none) {
          navigationBloc.navigatorKey.currentState!.push(
            NoConnectionScreen.route(),
          );
        }

        // When emitted status excluding initial one is 'no connectivity'.
        if (connectivityCubit.lastState != ConnectivityStatus.unknown &&
            event == ConnectivityStatus.none) {
          // TODO show flashbar
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivityStatusStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This did not work because the localizations were not yet initialised when using this  mixing in the MaterialApp context.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve my goals ?
**I do want to listen and react on connection changes no matter what my current route is.**